# wxString(const std::string&) throws read access violation in debug build

Tags: c++, debugging, wxwidgets, wxstring

Like the title suggests the wxString constructor always throws an read access violation exception when I'm running my program in debug mode (**not** in release mode). I guessed it has something to do with encoding, but I dont know how to fix it.
The problem occured when I ported my project from Visual Studio to CMake.

This:

```
wxString str(std::string("Hello world!"));
```

throws the exception:

```
Exception 0xc0000005 encountered at address 0x7ffda0bd8670: Access violation reading location 0xffffffffffffffff
```

I've looked into the disassembly and wxWidgets throws at

```
wxMBConv::cMB2WC(char const *,unsigned __int64,unsigned __int64 *)const :
  [...]
  callq  *(%rax)
  [...]
```

The build specs are:

```
CMake ver. 3.20.2 in Debug mode
MSVC ver. 16.0 with architecture amd64
LLDB ver. 9.0
wxWidgets ver. 3.1.5#2
```

All files are encoded in UTF-8 and I would prefer to use UTF-8 with narrow strings

Comment: are you saying that with MSVC that didn't occur?

Comment: No, this has nothing to do with encoding, there is either some subtly build mismatch (i.e. you've compiled the library and your compiler with different compiler options) or a bad bug elsewhere in your program. To distinguish between the 2 cases, add the line above to the minimal wxWidgets sample (`samples/minimal` in its source tree) and check if you can still reproduce the problem there.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the problem myself.
Thanks to vcpkg CMake links the debug build against the release build of wxwidgets, which causes the problems.
The issue has been reported here:
[vcpkg issue 18066](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/issues/18066)

but hasn't been fixed as of now